# Ubuntu 12.10 Wireless internet works but wired internet with Ethernet doesn't

Tags: 12.10, ethernet

I've recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 as a dual boot with Windows 7 but I've found my that neither operating systems can detect any of my ethernet cables. Wireless internet does work on both though.
My LAN driver is Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller. Since I'm new to Ubuntu I haven't tried much to fix it on Ubuntu, but I've tried a variety of things on windows like re installing the driver.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

download this file:

http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2

and write following commands in terminal

```
tar -xvf compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2
cd ccompat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc
scripts/driver-select alx
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```

Comment: I've tired the following but got stuck at running sudo make in the terminal, it gives:make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/build'
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thread on this same subject that may help. It is basically the same thing but you need to install the linux-headers-generic too.
[[SOLVED] Lenova G480/Atheros AR8162 Woes](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050126&highlight=alx)

Also if you have wireless working you can try downloading the latest updates and restarting. That fixed my wired internet problem.